# How do i grep a list of words with a specific letter listed twice or more?

Tags: regex, linux, terminal, grep

If I'm supposted to grep out every word that contains the letter 'w' twice, how am I supposed to do this?

When I try all I get is the words with two 'w's next to each other.

I've tried:

```
grep -P "(?=.*w)(?=.*w)" /usr/share/dict/words
egrep "(?=.*w)(?=.*w)" /usr/share/dict/words
cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep 'w' | grep 'w'
```

but nothing gives me the results that I want.  How can I do that?

Comment: an example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: `grep 'w.*w' /usr/share/dict/words` or `grep 'ww' /usr/share/dict/words`, the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: you mean exactly two w's?

Comment: sorry, i meant every word with atleast two or more 'w's

Comment: @andolini Do they have to be consecutive or can they be anywhere within the word?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this grep:

```
grep -Eo '\bw\w*w\w*\b'
```

**Example:**

```
echo 'abcw wowed drew won now wow watch' | grep -Eo '\bw\w*w\w*\b'
wowed
wow
```

Answer (score 0):

The below grep would grab the words which has atleast two `w`'s.

```
$ echo 'foo bar wow bar work wallewow' | grep -oP '\S*w\S*w\S*'
wow
wallewow
```

Answer (score 0):

To search `/usr/share/dict/words` for words containing the character `w` twice with arbitrary characters between them,

```
grep 'w.*w' /usr/share/dict/words
```

The problem with the zero-width assertion you used is that it will not skip forward.  So `(?=.*w)(?=.*w)` will find the first `w` character twice.  Similarly, `grep 'w' | grep 'w'` will find the first `w` character and pipe the line containing it to another instance of `grep` which does the same thing.

(The standard file `/usr/share/dict/words` contains one word per line, so we can use "word" above when we really mean "line", which is what `grep` and friends operates on.  Really grepping words out of free-form text is somewhat more involved.)